# ConnectionError: how to handle this error?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have got the following error:

> ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in
>
> ---> 16 df['List'] = df['Link'].apply(get_all_links)
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in
> apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)    4106
> else:    4107                 values = self.astype(object)._values
> -> 4108                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)    4109     4110         if len(mapped) and
> isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
>
> pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()
>
> in get_all_links(url)
> 7     # but that's outside the scope here
> 8     print(url)
> ----> 9     soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
> 10
> 11     return [a.attrs.get('href', '') for a in soup.find_all('a')]
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py in get(url,
> params, **kwargs)
> 74
> 75     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
> ---> 76     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
> 77
> 78
>
> ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))

I would say that a `try/except` condition might fix the issue. Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
def get_all_links(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

    return [a.attrs.get('href', '') for a in soup.find_all('a')]

df['List'] = df['Link'].apply(get_all_links)
```

I think all the information are shared. The website that seems causing the issue should be 'https://www.puppetstringnews.com/'.

An example of urls to test:

```
https://www.stackoverflow.com
https://deepclips.com/
https://www.puppetstringnews.com/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to open that website in the browser ? It first prompts you with an certificate error, and when you click "accept risk and continue", it gives an 404 Not Found error. The error probably is at the server side of that website, not in your code. To verify that, you can try another webpage. But with this one, you will never get the expected output. To skip such erroneous websites, wrap your `get_all_links` function body into a `try` / `except Exception as e`. Additionally, in the `except` clause, you should `print("Error with url %s : %s" % (url, e))`.

Comment: @Val you have to move the `Return` statement __before__ the `except` (inside the `try` block)

Comment: @Val no problem !

Comment: @Val could you maybe post some of the urls for testing purposes ?

Comment: I updated the question including three urls (just for testing). Thanks, Programmer

Comment: good day dar Programmer - thanks alot! this looks aweseome